# Return an integer array not working properly

Tags: if-statement

I am attempting to return an array from an else statement, but it is not working.

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

This solution doesn't work and returns {0,10}

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        if(nums.length == 0) return null;
        int[] numss = {0, 10};
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> s = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(s.getOrDefault(nums[i], 0) == 0) {
                s.put(target-nums[i], i);
            }
            else {
                numss[0] = i; 
                numss[1] = s.get(nums[i]);
                return numss;
            }
        }
        return numss;
    }
}
```

This solution works (Only change below is what the if-statement evalutates)

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        if(nums.length == 0) return null;
        int[] numss = {0, 10};
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> s = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(s.getOrDefault(nums[i], -1) == -1) {
                s.put(target-nums[i], i);
            }
            else {
                numss[0] = i; 
                numss[1] = s.get(nums[i]);
                return numss;
            }
        }
        return numss;
    }
}
```

This solution works

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        if(nums.length == 0) return null;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> s = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(s.getOrDefault(nums[i], -1) != -1) {
                    return new int[]{ i, s.get(nums[i]) };
                }
                s.put(target - nums[i], i);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
    }
}
```

Why is my else statement unable to return the array and stop the function or seemingly the if-else statement fail to even work properly?

Answer (score 0):

The actual value you're looking for in the second iteration is at index 0(2). So in your first example, the code will be going into the putting into hash structure block instead of returning the solution. In your other example, the code is going into the right block and returning the solution.

Comment: By index 0(2) I presume you mean the second position of the array?

Comment: The reason the first block does not work is because I do map.put(7,0), so when I come into the second iteration I check for map.getOrDefault(7, 0), which returns 0 and thus '=='0 and does not go to the else statement.